# How can I prove this relation?(multiset)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$\left(\!\!{2n\choose n}\!\!\right)=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\!\!{n\choose k}\!\!\right)\left(\!\!{n\choose n-k}\!\!\right)$

(the notation of the multiset is maybe not the best in latex)

Well, it's obvious that $\left(\!\!{n\choose k}\!\!\right)=\binom{n+k-1}{k}=\binom{(n+k-1)!}{k!(n-1)!}=\binom{n\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n+k-1)}{k!}$

I don't see how can be the left hand side equal to the right hand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to save some annoyance with the notation, we use $M(n,k)$ instead of $\left(\binom{n}{k}\right)$.

A store sells $n$ different **kinds** of doughnut, and $n$ different **kinds** of muffin. It has many doughnuts of each kind, and many muffins of each kind.

We want to choose a multiset of $n$ treats. This can be done in $M(2n,n)$ ways.  We count this another way.

Perhaps we will choose $0$ doughnuts and $n$ muffins. That can be done in $M(n,0)M(n,n)$ ways. Or perhaps we will choose $1$ doughnut and $n-1$ muffins. That can be done in $M(n,1)M(n,n-1)$ ways. And so on. In general we can choose a multiset of $k$ doughnuts and $n-k$ muffins in $M(n,k)M(n,n-k)$ ways. Add up.